# Couchdb 3.1.1 increases disk latency gradually over weeks

Tags: linux, performance, io, latency, couchdb

I've been dealing with this issue for weeks now.

I have the followin scenario:

```
couchdb2.3.1-A <===> couchdb2.3.1-B <===> couchdb3.1.1-A <===> couchdb3.1.1-B
```

where `<===>` represents two pull replications, one configured on each side. i.e: couchdb1 pulls from couchdb2 and viceversa.

Couchdb is running in docker containers

If a write is made at `couchdb2.3.1-A`, it has to make it through all servers until it comes to `couchdb3.1.1-B`.

Al of them has an exclusive HDD. Couchdb does not share disk with any other service.

`couchdb2.3.1` `A` and `B` have no problem.

`couchdb3.1.1-A` gradually started to increase disk latency over time. So we stopped making write requests to it and started to talk only with `couchdb3.1.1-B`. `couchdb3.1.1-A` still receives writes but only by replication protocol. Disk latency did not change.

Changes we've made since problem started:

- Upgraded kernel from `4.15.0-55-generic` to `5.4.0-88-generic`
- Upgraded ubuntu from `18.04` to `20.04`
- Deleted `_global_changes` database from `couchdb3.1.1-A`

More info:

- Couchdb is using docker local-persist volumes.
- Disks are WD Purple for `2.3.1` couchdbs and WD Black for `3.1.1` couchdbs.
- We have only one database of `88GiB` and 2 views: one of `22GB` and a little one of `30MB` (highly updated)
- `docker stats` shows that couchdb3.1.1 uses lot of memory compared to 2.3.1:

  - `3.5GiB` for couchdb3.1.1-A (not receiving direct write requests)
  - `8.0GiB` for couchdb3.1.1-A (receiving both read and write requests)
  - `226MiB` for 2.3.1-A
  - `552MiB` for 2.3.1-B
- Database compaction is run at night. Problem only occurs over day, when most of the writes are made.
- Most of config is default.

Latency graph from munin monitoring:

[disk latency](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rWvfd.png)

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Any hint here? :(